# AVPlayer Sound Level meter

Tags: xcode

I am using AVPlayer for a network stream App. I need to develop a Sound level meter but most of the stuff around works with AVAudioPlayer.

Could someone please suggest how this can be achieved. Any help or lead would really be appreciated.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/a/16046183/1474080

Comment: Did you find anything that works?

Comment: Try this https://github.com/akhilcb/ACBAVPlayerExtension